# php .htaccess create subdomain excluding query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following records in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9].*)$  /folder/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What I want is:
Show `example.com/folder/user/0`'s content by accessing `user.example.com/0`
When I access `user.example.com/0` my link looks like: `user.example.com/folder/user/0`
How can I fix it?

Comment: @apokryfos I create dynamic subdomains on the fly so I suppose I should rewrite url. I am new to .htaccess so I can't tell you what I want =)

Comment: This can't be done via .htaccess because using a different host will cause a redirect.

Comment: @apokryfos then I should make redirect? Wanna know how...

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that would take any URL of the form `user.example.com/N` and make it into a redirect to `example.com/folder/user/N`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$  http://example.com/folder/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The redirect happens because of the change of host. This means the user's browser bar will become `example.com/folder/user/N`